# Colombia travel visa for Indian citizen already having Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, south-america, colombia, spanish-language

Since Colombian embassy's (in Germany as well as in India) ***website is in Spanish***, I am not able to gather the information needed.

I need to know if an Indian national, who already has Schengen Visa (for Schengen area in Europe), need to apply for Colombian visa to travel from Germany to Colombia.

I read that in the year 2017, some new visa rules have been implemented by the Colombian government, and according to it, citizens of India, China, Thailand etc don't need a Colombia visa if they already have a valid Schengen visa.

It would be very nice if somebody could guide me, where to find the travel visa information on this [Consulate of Colombia in Frankfurt page](http://frankfurt.consulado.gov.co/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the info you need, select ‘Visa’ under ‘Servicios Consulares’, then on the next page select ‘¿Necesito una visa?
Assuming you have an ordinary Indian passport and want a standard visit visa, the website response (copied below) states that a holder of a US or Schengen Visa valid for at least 180 days at the date of entering Columbia (not a transit visa) or a residence permit doesn’t need a visa to enter Columbia. Otherwise a visa is required.
“No necesita visa para ingresar a Colombia si es titular de visa de EEUU o Schengen con una vigencia mínima de 180 días al momento del ingreso a Colombia (no es admisible visa para tránsito aeroportuario) o es titular de residencia en un estado miembro del espacio Schengen o de los Estados Unidos de América. En caso contrario:
Debe solicitar visa. Póngase en contacto con el consulado de Colombia más cercano a su lugar actual de residencia.
VISA DE VISITANTE - TIPO V: prevista para el extranjero que quiera visitar Colombia una o varias veces o permanecer temporalmente en el país sin establecerse de manera permanente.”

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is still looking for this. Here is some official documentation stating that Indians with Schengen or US Visa may enter Colombia.

https://www.cancilleria.gov.co/sites/default/files/FOTOS2018/resolucion_10535_del_14_de_diciembre_de_2018.pdf

[image: Resolucion 10535]